# Why is the return value of MPI_Comm_size signed?

Tags: c, mpi

[MPI_Comm_size](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Comm_size.3.php) returns the number of MPI processes. Obviously that cannot be negative. Is there a specific reason for returning an signed `int` as opposed to and unsigned one? The documentation does not mention a possible returned negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is a status/error code, but yes the size ptr is expected to be a ptr to int.  I can't be sure, but this is probably mainly due to legacy, but it  is consistently used, such that you can easily have an integer loop from 0 to comm_size, and pass the iterator to e.g. MPI_Comm_rank which also expects a ptr to int.